# Jquery- issue with script

Tags: javascript, jquery

i stuck with an issue. I have UI part and Server part code. in UI i send the data to server side as json format.actually my problem is i wrote the follwing script. #btn_login click is for login and the page is working well.and for next "btn_AddDoc" click nothing is happening and the page reloads.

Olease advice.i dont have experience in script.

```
var userid ;
  $(function () {
     $("#dialog").dialog();
      //login button click
      $("#btn_login").click( function () {
          var GetLogDet = {};
          GetLogDet.Username =$("#username").val();
          GetLogDet.Password = $("#password").val();
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
             url: "http://localhost/EMRDMSService/Service.asmx/User_Login",
             data: "{lg:" + JSON.stringify(GetLogDet) + "}",
            // url: "http://localhost/EMRDMSService/Service.asmx/Permission_List",
             // data: "{userid:" + JSON.stringify(GetLogDet) + "}",

              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function (r) {                     


                              console.log(r.d.STAT);
              }
          });
      });
      //add document button click
      $("#btn_AddDoc").click( function () {
          var InsDocDet = {};
          InsDocDet.docname=$("#DocName").val();
          InsDocDet.file_name=$("#FlName").val();
          InsDocDet.ownerUser=1;
          InsDocDet.catid=$("#drp_cat").val();
          InsDocDet.createDatetime=new Date();
          InsDocDet.description_d=$("#Desc").val();
          InsDocDet.comments_=$("#cmnts").val();
          InsDocDet.deptid_=1;
          InsDocDet.con_type=1;
          InsDocDet.size_=1;
          InsDocDet.Doc_status="up";

          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
            // <!-- url: "http://localhost/EMRDMSService/Service.asmx/User_Login",-->
             url: "http://localhost/EMRDMSService/Service.asmx/Permission_List",
              data: "{ins_Doc:" + JSON.stringify(GetLogDet) + "}",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function (r) {                     


                              console.log(r.d.STAT);
              }
          });
      });


  });
```

Regards,

Sivajith S.

Comment: is #btn_AddDoc an <a> tag ? or form submit button ?

Comment: JavaScript code seems fine. Can you confirm type of button btn_AddDoc? is it Submit or Button?

Comment: <input type="submit" id="btn_AddDoc" class="login" value="Save">

Answer (score 0):

I see a typo in

`data: "{ins_Doc:" + JSON.stringify(GetLogDet) + "}",`

in the `$("#btn_AddDoc").click` function.

Try to change

`data: "{ins_Doc:" + JSON.stringify(GetLogDet) + "}",`

in

`data: "{ins_Doc:" + JSON.stringify(InsDocDet) + "}",`

Comment: @Daniele-I changed the code,but no change in response...i want  to know whether the entire page reloads when i click on the save button

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong in the page where the data are sent.
Can you edit the post and insert the code you use in the permission_list url?

Comment: In the other comment i saw that you use a submit button to call the function.

Unless it's necessary, you can replace the `type="submit"` with `type="button"` and the reloading will be gone.

You can also slightly change `$("#btn_AddDoc").click( function () {` with `$("#btn_AddDoc").click( function (e) {` and add `e.preventDefault();` inside the function.